# Register OnClickListerner for framework dialog box button?

Tags: android, dialog, video-streaming, android-alertdialog, android-videoview

I am facing a issue wherein I am trying to play a streaming video using RTSP in the android device. I am using videoview and everything works fine and nice. In few devices this video feed has some encoding problem and doesnt play. In these cases the videoview shows a dialog box with a message "Sorry Cant play this video" and "OK" button. I want to register a OnClickListerner for this OK button. I dont create this dialog box and so I dont have a reference in  my class. Guess this dialog box is a framework one.

I need do some important operations in this OnclickListerner so need to register to the OK button of this dialog box. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Adding Logcat Logs

you cna see at the end of the logs that MediaPlayer is displaying some error. I have my activity implement onErrorListerner and I did set my activity as videoView's onErrorListerner. **But still my errorlisterner never gets called...** i looking to resolve this issue ASAP.. any help is appreciated...

```
ERROR/MediaPlayer(4243): onHDMIStateChanged
ERROR/voaEngine(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    voaEngine.cpp  voaInit  22    Flag: 1
ERROR/voaEngine(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    voaEngine.cpp  voaSetParam  66    VOAP_IDF_onFirstRef
ERROR/voaEngine(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    voaEngine.cpp  voaSetParam  70    VOAP_IDF_initCheck
ERROR/CDllLoad(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    CDllLoad.cpp  LoadLib  221    Load module libvoOMXME.so!
ERROR/voaEngine(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    voaEngine.cpp  voaSetParam  74    VOAP_IDF_setDataSourceURL
ERROR/CVOMEPlayer(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    CVOMEPlayer.cpp  SetSource  147    Source: rtsp://a1052.l82402None.c82402.g.lq.akamaistream.net/7/1052/82402/v0001/cnbc.download.akamai.com/23727/sdp_!/apa1.sdp?auth=daEcpc4cOdnbLaAb.d_bnbMcLcwc7cFccc7-bnQmbB-bWG-QYQN&aifp=abcq&reporting=part="E*TRADE FINANCIAL"|parttype=STREAM
ERROR/CVOMEPlayer(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD AFD4A830:    CVOMEPlayer.cpp  SetSource  193    Count: 1
ERROR/voaEngine(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 00016C08:    voaEngine.cpp  voaSetParam  89    VOAP_IDF_prepareAsync
ERROR/voOMXCfg(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp  Open  389    Read 459 bytes
ERROR/voOMXCfg(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp  Open  389    Read 474 bytes
ERROR/voOMXCfg(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp  Open  366    The config file vomeComp_RTSP.cfg could not be opened!
ERROR/CVOMEPlayer(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    CVOMEPlayer.cpp  BuildGraph  387    start to build graph!
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  SetCoreFile  114    OMX Core file is libvoOMXOne.so
ERROR/Util(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXBaseGraph.cpp  OMX_mmLoadLib  194    Load libvoOMXOne.so ... 0xb0011ccc
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Warning THD 0001FF38: voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  SetCoreFile  163    m_fSetWorkingPath is 0X8121B8B8
ERROR/voOMXCfg(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXBaseConfig.cpp  Open  366    The config file vomeOne.cfg could not be opened!
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 0 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.FileSource
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 1 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Audio.Decoder.XXX
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 2 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Audio.Sink
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 3 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Video.Decoder.XXX
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 4 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Video.Sink
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 5 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Clock.Time
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 6 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.G1Video.Capture
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 7 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.G1Audio.Capture
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 8 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Video.Encoder.XXX
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 9 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Audio.Encoder.XXX
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 10 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.FileSink
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 11 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.DataSource
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 12 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Audio.Effect
ERROR/voCOMXCoreLoader(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXCoreLoader.cpp  OMX_ComponentNameEnum  443    The 13 Component Name is OMX.VisualOn.Video.Effect
ERROR/(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   CBaseConfig.cpp  Open  373    The config file vommcodec.cfg could not be opened!
ERROR/voCOMXFileSource(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    voCOMXFileSource.cpp  voCOMXFileSource  86    Name OMX.VisualOn.FileSource.
ERROR/CDllLoad(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    CDllLoad.cpp  LoadLib  221    Load module libHTC_mm_property.so!
ERROR/MM_PROPERTY(64): can not match property 'rtspproxyip'
ERROR/CDllLoad(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    CDllLoad.cpp  FreeLib  270    Free module libHTC_mm_property.so!
ERROR/voStreaming(64): voStreaming Permission denied,[/data/local/visualonLog_rtsp/],create log directory fails
ERROR/CDllLoad(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    CDllLoad.cpp  LoadLib  221    Load module libvoSrcRTSP.so!
ERROR/CRTSPSource(64): @@@VOLOG Info THD 0001FF38:    CRTSPSource.cpp  HandleStreamEvent  554    Error Event 3002
ERROR/CRTSPSource(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   CRTSPSource.cpp  LoadSource  255    VOID_STREAMING_OPENURL failed. 0X83000007
ERROR/voCOMXFileSource(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXFileSource.cpp  LoadFile  555    m_pSource->LoadSource was failed. 0X83000007
ERROR/voCOMXCompBaseChain(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXCompBaseChain.cpp  AddSource  292    ##########    File Name is rtsp://..........(purposely hidden)
ERROR/voCOMXCompBaseChain(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXCompBaseChain.cpp  AddSource  306    It could not load the source component.
ERROR/Util(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   voCOMXBaseGraph.cpp  Playback  782    m_pChain->AddSource!
ERROR/CVOMEPlayer(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   CVOMEPlayer.cpp  BuildGraph  421    m_fAPI.Playback error 
ERROR/CVOMEPlayer(64): @@@VOLOG Error THD 0001FF38:   CVOMEPlayer.cpp  NotifyOpenSource  342    BuildGraph failed!.
ERROR/MediaPlayer(4243): error (1, -1)
ERROR/MediaPlayer(4243): Error (1,-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your own `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener` by using `myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(...)`. The default dialog with "Sorry can't play the video" will not be displayed but the listener instance will allow you to create your own `AlertDialog` (or whatever suits your need) and handle any action on this dialog.

Comment: I have added logs to my question. Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: Well, logcat shows that there's definitely an error while loading the video stream. But without any code, I cannot tell why the onErrorListener is never called...

Comment: Hi Ocus, I got it working now. I was trying to implement the MediaPlayerControl.onErrorListerner instead of the MediaPlayer.onErrorListerner. I looked into the implementation of videoview and identified my problem... thanks for your help and apprecitae it.. :-)